# PhpStorm not recognizing "IF NOT EXISTS " sql request

Tags: mysql, sql, phpstorm

I connected MySQL database to my **PhpStorm** and its recognize simple sql requests.In my screenshot as you can see it is not recognize `creategrop2help` function. [image: here]. What can i do with this? ...if I leave this, will this work?

Comment: You should post code as formatted text. It looks like you are missing a closing bracket in your `exist` statement.

Comment: In general: the pattern that IDE uses cannot cover ALL possible situations (otherwise it becomes too slow (affects editing experience a lot) or makes false positives). You can create custom Language Injection rule (similar to original one) or inject SQL Language into such string manually (PHPDoc comment -- just use Alt+Enter menu). Another thing: you are using quite old IDE version (almost 3 years old) .. so 2nd option may not be available there.

Comment: @LazyOne I got it in 2016

Comment: PhpStorm v9, v10, v2016.1, 2016.2, 2016.3, 2017.1 ... latest is 2018.1 (which is like v17) ... so yeah -- your v9 (as per screenshot) is almost 3 years old. P.S. You can also use HEREDOC/NOWDOC syntax with `SQL` as a label -- current SQL dialect will be injected into such string.

Comment: *"if I leave this, will this work"* It will .. as long as code itself is OK. This is just detecting another language inside the string content -- it's for user convenience etc and does not affect the actual code execution.